# Is there a possibility to check if multiple columns of an entity contain one search key in JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is there a possibility to check if multiple or every column of an entity contains one key.

So I have multiple places which contain multiple addresses. 
An address does contain the id of its place, a name and an area. I want to filter out the addresses which contain a searchTerm s1 in either its name or area.

I did already try this, but sadly it didnt work for me.

```
fun findByPlaceIdAndNameIgnoreCaseOrAreaIgnoreCaseContaining(placeId: UUID, searchTerm: String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible. Just but the appropriate query in a `@Query` annotation.
I don't know Kotlin so the syntax is guess work on my side but I'm sure you figure it out based on this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Place p WHERE p.placeId = :placeID AND (UCASE(p.name) = UCASE(:searchTerm) OR UCASE(p.name) = UCASE(:searchTerm))")
fun search(placeId: UUID, searchTerm: String)
```